# select2 setting a value OR setting a default value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to understand why a solution I have does not work, below is that solution. In this solution str_current_status in devtool console returns literal "Cancelled"

```
$('#test').select2().val(str_current_status);
```

The above will not work for me. However the below 2 options will both work.

```
$('#test').select2().val('Cancelled');
```

OR (This second solution was found on accident and I've no clue why this works)

```
$('#test').select2().val(str_current_status.toString());
$('#test').select2().val(str_current_status.trim);
```

If anyone can show me the proper way to set select2 val based on a variable and do this WITHOUT using change I would love to know the correct solution.

Comment: The `str_current_status` value *cannot* be `Cancelled` as you expect, otherwise it would work. Without knowing exactly what type and value it holds, we can't really help. How have you determined it holds `Cancelled`? Try `console.log(str_current_status)` and `console.log(typeof str_current_status)`

Comment: In F12 console I use a breakpoint when str_current_status exists and I type into console str_current_status and the response is "Cancelled"

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I get the following when I enter the above concole.logs. ```console.log(str_current_status)            - Cancelled```
```console.log(typeof str_current_status) - string```